# How to add hash (#) in the URLFOR

Tags: visualforce

I have tried few different way but I get the error `Syntax error`

Using apex:commandButton

```
<apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!URLFOR($Page.Employee, null, [id=URLENCODE($CurrentPage.Parameters.id)])}" />
```

tried

//Able to save but when click on the button it wipes out the id value

```
action="{!URLFOR($Page.Employee, null, [id=URLENCODE($CurrentPage.Parameters.id#tab1)])}"
```

or Syntax Error msg

```
action="{!URLFOR($Page.Employee, null, [id=URLENCODE($CurrentPage.Parameters.id,#tab1)])}"
```

or Syntax Error msg

```
action="{!URLFOR($Page.Employee, null, [id=URLENCODE($CurrentPage.Parameters.id,URLENCODE(#tab1))])}"
```

Comment: tried got the Syntax error

Comment: Check my answer below..Ignore my above comment(Deleted the comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton 
                value="Back" 
                action="{!URLFOR($Page.PdfPage, null, 
                            [id=$CurrentPage.Parameters.id + '#menu'])}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**UPDATE:** (This one does not encode URL as the above one as we are just appending `href` outside the `URLFOR` function.)

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton 
                value="Back" 
                action="{!URLFOR($Page.PdfPage, null, 
                            [id=$CurrentPage.Parameters.id]) +'#menu'}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**UPDATE2:**

After reading Adrian's comment, I tried this variation also and it worked. (Concatenating parameters to `URLFOR` formula value )

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton 
                value="Back" 
                action="{!URLFOR($Page.PdfPage, null, 
                            [id=$CurrentPage.Parameters.id]) +'#menu?id1=1234'}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Try everything in one line..For readability purpose, I split it into two lines.

Comment: What if more parameters get added in later? I wonder if you can add it outside the `URLFOR` function entirely?

Comment: @AdrianLarson, I am not sure but as per the documentation, it looks like all the parameters should be with in those square brackets.

Comment: okay so i do not get any errors but when i click the back button instead of getting `#` in the url i'm getting `%23` hence it mixed with the id so here is what i'm getting when i click the back button `https://xxxx.visual.force.com/apex/employee?id=a08V00000031mWA%23tab1`

Comment: @NickKahn Check the updated answer.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I was curious after you comment and looks like we can add parameters from outside `URLFOR` formula.

Comment: 1+ its working now with URLENCODE or without. `action="{!URLFOR($Page.Employee, null, [id=URLENCODE($CurrentPage.Parameters.id)] + '#menu'}"`

Answer (score 0):

Corrent syntax is as follows:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!URLFOR($Page.VFP, null,[id=URLENCODE($CurrentPage.Parameters.id)+ '#tab1'])}" />
```